# Running a grails application on Amazon EC2

Tags: grails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a Grails application which I run on an Amazon EC2 instance. I usually start this application by using Putty from my windows machine to log into it and change to the application's home directory and type 'grails run-app'. This approach works fine when developing but what if I wish to leave the application running for testers? Is there any way I can make it so that the application will continue to run on the Amazon EC2 machine even when I quit my Putty link to it or turn off my windows computer that I use to access the EC2?

Comment: 1. Set up a Tomcat server, package your app, and deploy it. 2. `nohup grails run-app &`. 1 is a much better option than 2 IMHO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never use `grails run-app` for anything other than testing the app locally while developing.

- build a .war file using the `grails war` command
- deploy it to Tomcat's `webapps` directory
- start Tomcat (if it's not already running)